# Difference in Predicted output in polynomial regression

Tags: regression, polynomial

In polynomial regression when the coefficients applied to calculate the predicted values manually is different from the output generated from the software. How to get the correct predicted values using polynomial regression in R when the Independent values increases

lm1 <- lm(Sales ~ poly(Rank,8,raw= T),data=beauty_poly)

Comment: Fitting a simple data set to a straight line might help in solving the problem.